# The if statement in the nested loop stops my function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I am writing a function which takes as first argument an array (`arr1`), and then N number of arguments (`arr2`), by which it removes the N arguments (`arr2`) from the array (`arr1`). The function seems to be doing the job, except it stops immediately when the if statement becomes true. I know this because if I remove the if statement the loops are iterated till the end. Any ideas what I did wrong?

So below the returned array should be ['A','B','E'].

```
const removeFromArray = function(arr1, arr2) {
    let arr_new = arr1;
    first_loop:
    for (const [y, elem] of arr1.entries()) {
        for (let i=1; i<arguments.length; i++) {
            if ((elem === arguments[i])) {
                arr_new.splice(y);
            }
        }
    }
    return arr_new;
}

alert(removeFromArray(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E'],'C','D'));
```

Comment: Note that `let arr_new = arr1;` does **not** make a copy of `arr1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate take on what you're trying to accomplish. While arrow functions don't have `arguments`, you can still emulate it through `rest parameters`. Then you can just use a filter

```js
const removeFromArray = (...args) => {
  let arr1 = args[0], arr2 = args.slice(1)
  return arr1.filter(a => arr2.indexOf(a) === -1)
}

console.log(removeFromArray(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'C', 'D'));
```

Comment: Thanks this was clear. Just a question do you think my original method of running two loops could have worked? I adjusted the splice so that it removes only one element from the array, but the results are still flawed as it removes only one element and doesn't iterate through the other ```arr2``` arguments. I guess this has something to do with ```let arr_new = arr1;``` not doing the copy?

Comment: @fg42 - I must admit, when I tried to unravel your technique of using .entries() and then looping through `arguments`  I got a bit lost and at that point decided to pursue a similar but more optimized solution. I think my solution has the spirit of what you were doing but perhaps in an easier to read fashion

Answer (score 1):

`splice` modify original array so when you call it. It just removes all elements from `y` until the end of `arr_new` and `arr_new` refers to `arr1`.

```
const foo = [1, 2, 3, 4];
foo.splice(2);
console.log(foo); // [1, 2]
```

`arr1.entries()` is an iterator which continue to track `arr1` internally so when you modify `arr1` it would **modify `entries`** too, so this is why your loop is stopped - there are **no elements** after splice

To fix this problem, you can modify your code

```
    if ((elem === arguments[i])) {
        arr_new.splice(y, /* remove only one element*/1);
    }
```

⚠️ P.s. solution above still has problems with indexes because you modify the original array and relay on that index. This lead to incorrect overall result

This is proper solution of remove from array, without modification and with better complexity O(n)

```
const removeFromArray = function(arr1, ...arr2) {
    const exclude = arr2.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        acc.add(curr);
        return acc;
    }, new Set());
    return arr1.filter((it) => {
        return !exclude.has(it)
    });
}
```